# "shift +" while rendering in ffmpeg, how to undo?

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line

I was rendering a video in ffmpeg and accidentally pressed "shift" and "+", and the below started happening.

What is this doing and how do I stop it and is it creating something I need to delete or worry about? And what do I do to delete it if so?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, all you did is increase verbosity. The <kbd>Shift</kbd> had no effect, but the <kbd>+</kbd> increased it. Press <kbd>-</kbd> to cycle back to a lower verbosity level.

Press <kbd>?</kbd> to see a list of all available commands.

If you want to not worry about accidental keypresses, you can add `-nostdin` to the command. Don't do this if one of your inputs is a pipe.